# Scilab displays an empty screen when executing it while using "dwm" but not while using "i3"

Tags: gui, window-manager, i3, dwm

## The context

This gif shows what happens when trying to opening `scilab` while using `i3`

[image]

This gif shows what happens when trying to opening `scilab` while using `dwm`

[image]

## The problem

I'm currently using `dwm` because using `tags` is more suitable in more workflow than using workspaces with `i3`, so in order to use `scilab` I have to switch back to `i3`.

## The question

Why does `dwm` behave like this while `i3` not?

By understanding the context, I will be able to search through [all the available `dwm` patches](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/) in order to discern whether a given one would be useful to solve this specific issue.

## The current workaround

`scilab-cli` runs well in both `dwm` and `i3`, I can plot graphs and perform any operation, so for the moment I can use `scilab-cli` while using `dwm`.

## Additional context

I wonder whether setting one of these environment variables might help

```
$ ./bin/scilab --randomtext 2>&1 | tail -n 6
  Several environment variables can be declared:
  SCIVERBOSE               Provides debugging information of the startup
  JAVA_HOME                Declares which Java Virtual Machine to use
  SCI_DISABLE_TK           Disables Tk (but not Tcl) features
  SCI_JAVA_ENABLE_HEADLESS Runs Java Headless VM (without GUI; Windows and Linux only)
  SCI_DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING Disable the catch by Scilab of exception (segfault, ...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common rendering issue with Java applications and non-reparenting window managers. There are 2 solutions:

1. Use [wmname](https://tools.suckless.org/x/wmname/) to impersonate another window manager, e.g.

   ```
   $ wmname LG3D
   ```
2. Set no-reparenting flag for JDK

   ```
   export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
   ```

Comment: Thanks. The GUI now opens correctly. I didn't need to execute step 1, by the way. That is, I just needed to execute the following command `_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1 scilab` in an interactive shell. If you don't mind me asking, what other widely used programs behave like this?

Comment: NetBeans, Eclipse, etc. Anything written in Java.